# Are there any additional quests/expansions for Dragon Age that are not developed by Bioware?

Tags: pc, dragon-age-origins

After a whole year, and before Dragon Age 2, I am having a second playthrough. I would love to add some additional content to spice up a bit the fun, and I was hoping for some extra developed by some passionate gamers. Is there anything out there that is worth to install and try that is not from BioWare?

(I have already most of the expansion released from BioWare)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dragon Age Nexus](http://www.dragonagenexus.com) is probably the reference point for all Dragon Age mods and tweaks.

I am still finishing `Dragon Age` so I cannot really suggest one or another but there all mods are divided by category and **voted by users**. In your specific case you can take a look to:

- [Quest & Adventures](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/cat.php?id=27)
- [Dungeons](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/cat.php?id=11)
- [Cities, Towns & Villages](http://www.dragonagenexus.com/downloads/cat.php?id=8)

Comment: Thx for the info. The only negative thing about tha resource it is that you have to register. I found out by googling that Bioware has those projects on their website as well, where I can download those files without registering: http://social.bioware.com/browse_bw_projects.php

Comment: I found out even this interesting articles: http://www.pcgamer.com/2010/11/18/18-essential-dragon-age-mods/

Comment: Yeah, registration is needed but it's a good site managed well. You can log also to Fallout Nexus and New Vegas Nexus with the same account :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you are asking for quests not developed by Bioware, you probably weren't aware of [*A Tale of Orzammar*](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/A_Tale_of_Orzammar), which is the only campaign mod that was created by Bioware, but not included in any version of *Dragon Age: Origins*. It is a short, voiceless prologue to the Dwarven Noble Origin and was released as a promotion for the December 2009 edition of *PC Gamer*. Furthermore, it is treated as canon.

> Tapster's Tavern is the one place where all levels of the rigidly stratified Dwarven society can meet. As such, it is an excellent place for deals to be made - often of a somewhat illicit nature. You've heard word that a Dwarven Noble is looking to hire an adventurer for a small foray into the Deep Roads. It should pay well - and, perhaps give you some insight into the politics of Orzammar. Knowledge that can be worth far more than gold...